# Symfony2 disable logs in test environment

Tags: php, symfony, logging, config, monolog

How to disable any logs in test environment? Question related to correct monolog setup in `config_test.yml` file, that inherited from `config_dev.yml`, where config looks like this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      grouped_main
        streamed_main:
            type:   stream
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  debug
        grouped_main:
            type:    group
            members: [streamed_main]
        console:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_VERBOSE: INFO
                VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE: DEBUG
            channels: ["!doctrine"]
        console_very_verbose:
            type:   console
            bubble: false
            verbosity_levels:
                VERBOSITY_VERBOSE: NOTICE
                VERBOSITY_VERY_VERBOSE: NOTICE
                VERBOSITY_DEBUG: DEBUG
            channels: ["doctrine"]
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the inheritance to change the type of the handler, and even the level:

config_test.yml

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      grouped_main
        streamed_main:
            type:   fingers_crossed
            path:   "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level:  error
```

You can also change to `bubble: false`

Maybe you can also reconsider no using logs, you can save it on syslog and other backends which can be more convenient to you!

Comment: Can you please explain what this code is doing? Will monolog save less data?